# Field missing for stdClass php

Tags: php

```
$resp = new stdClass();
$resp->first_name->type = "select";
$resp->first_name->required = 'true';
$resp->first_name->type_meta->options[0] = "opt 1";
$resp->first_name->type_meta->options[1] = "opt 2";
$resp->first_name->type_meta->options[2] = "opt 3";
$resp->last_name->type = "text";
$resp->last_name->required = 'true';
$resp->last_name->type_meta=new stdClass();
```

Why does my script won't work on my php file but works on w3schools php try it compiler. The error I get is
*Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property "type" on null*

Even though I am using stdClass() to create an object so why it gives null for type field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the sub-properties first. A property without a value is null, so you need to make it an stdClass as well and then you can go.

```
$resp = new stdClass();
$resp->first_name = new stdClass();
$resp->first_name->type = "select";
$resp->first_name->required = 'true';
$resp->first_name->type_meta = new stdClass();
$resp->first_name->type_meta->options[0] = "opt 1";
$resp->first_name->type_meta->options[1] = "opt 2";
$resp->first_name->type_meta->options[2] = "opt 3";
$resp->last_name = new stdClass();
$resp->last_name->type = "text";
$resp->last_name->required = 'true';
$resp->last_name->type_meta=new stdClass();
```

Comment: Thank you it works as expected now but I am unclear on the point where it works on w3schools compiler and not locally on my machine.

Comment: @MuhammadFahad - It's time to ditch w3scools completely. I believe they have become a bit better in recent years, but they are infamous for suggesting bad practices and bad code. If you want a simple online sandbox to test some PHP code in, I recommend something like https://3v4l.org (just one of many alternatives), There you can also define which PHP versions you want to test it with. Here's the code in your question on that site: https://3v4l.org/sKMBK

Answer (score 0):

you need to set a value for `$resp->first_name` and `$resp->last_name` because there values is null or if you are using php 8 you can use null safer operator like this : `$resp->first_name?->type = "select";`

Comment: Upon using null safe operator I get 
Can't use nullsafe operator in write context